# Error: Unexpected value 'Http' imported by the module 'AppModule' at SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError

Tags: angular

I've checked my code several times and tried finding similar problems on the web and stackoverflow, but I'm out of ideas by now, I simply can't see my mistake. Do you have any recommendations what I should examine next?

UPDATE: When I debug my Configuration Class I can see, that my json-Configurations files are read and the values are stored into my configuration variables correctly on App-Initialize (see load()-function of app.config.ts on plnkr).
BUT if I want to get the values back from this configuration varibales e.g. line 39 of "werkzeug.service.ts"

```
let host:string = this.config.getConfig('host');
```

The following error appears:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'host' of null
    at AppConfig.getConfig (http://localhost:3000/app/app.config.js:31:27)
    at WerkzeugService.getSollIstWerkzeugBySchrankAndAnsicht (http://localhost:3000/app/werkzeug.service.js:47:32)
    at AppComponent.ngAfterViewInit (http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js:37:30)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:44:71)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12206:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12353:48)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9375:24)
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8299:71)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ApplicationRef_.tick (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8299:29)
    at ApplicationRef_._loadComponent (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8274:18)
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8262:18)
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8091:93)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at PlatformRef_._moduleDoBootstrap
```

Here is my project setup: http://plnkr.co/edit/QsaOtnqFr0Ky9Qwz21SP?p=preview

Comment: Is your `@NgModule` still importing the `Http`?

Comment: Despite the fact that you've changed your question completely.. You don't have a `systemjs.config.js` which you are trying to import in your `index.html`. You don't have your `node_modules` either. You can click new at the top left -> Angular -> 2.0.x to create a new plunker for your angular2 template and you don't need to write `.js` and `.js.map` files

Comment: I added the missing file systemjs.config.js to plnkr.

Comment: I don't see it. Did you forget to update it?

Comment: I didn´t add node_modules, because it contains of many libraries which are laoded by npm. The .js and .js.map files are not handwritten but all generated.

Comment: No I meant i didn't see the system config file cuz you updated your plunker after I commented.

Comment: Did you check the console? You are trying to import node_modules in your index.html but they aren't there so you are getting an exception.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`HttpModule` should be in the `imports` but `Http` shouldn't be.

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ AppConfig, { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initConfig, deps: [AppConfig], multi: true }]  
})
```

Example `http.get` Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/60E2qb9gOjvkEAeR5CtE?p=info

Comment: @anyones `HttpModule` is still in `providers` in your question. And where does `Http` come from in your `imports`?

Comment: Alright, let me try without the `HttpModule` in `providers`. Why shouldn't it be there? The `Http` comes from `import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';` Thanks for looking into it! UPDATE:Now I removed the `HttpModule` from `providers`, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @anyones you shouldn't import `Http` in your module. You should use it in your component/injectable. I don't know which tutorial you are using but please read the official documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html I will add an http plunker as an example to my question.

Comment: Ok, I fixed my problem.
Now the serverConfig is in scope and I have access to the values in my service classes (WerkzeugService and SchrankService).
The interessting code snippets are in main.ts (provide my server configuration on initPromise):
And in app.components.ts (injecting the serverConfiguration and consign it to my both service classes):
I updated plnkr so you can see the actual code.
http://plnkr.co/edit/IawzlGDVYyUObJjxkDK8?p=preview

@echonax: Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: @anyones glad you figured it out :-)